# Differentiability of function defined as integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Suppose

$$F(x) := \int_0^1 f(t,x) dt $$

is well-defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. I would like to show that $F(x)$ is not differentiable at $0$. Is it enough to show that $\partial_x f(t,0)$ is not integrable over $t \in (0,1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would not. Let's say $f$ is a function such that $\partial_x f(t,0)$ is not integrable. I define 
$$\tilde f(t,x) = \begin{cases} f(2t,x),\quad & 0\le t\le 1/2 \\ -f(2t-1,x),\quad &1/2\le t\le 1 \end{cases}$$
Although $\partial_x \tilde f(t,0)$ is still not integrable, the function $F$ is identically zero.

Comment: Nice. Thank you very much. Is there any way to determine the (non-)differentiability of $F$ without actually computing $$\int_0^1 \frac{f(t,h) - f(t,0)}{h} dt$$ ?

My question is coming from a real problem where I can compute derivatives of $f$ w.r.t $x$ but cannot explicitly integrate $f$ w.r.t $t$.

Comment: @mathman Sure. If you want to prove nondifferentiability, you decide if it is going to be through an infinite slope (failure of Lipschitz condition) or some oscillation. Then you look for bits of the integral that create such things, show they are big, and the other, potentially counteracting bits, are not big enough to cancel them.